# How with, where operators work in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How do `with, where` eloquent operators work in Laravel?

Is it possible to see is build result SQL query after using `with`, `where` or these operators applied only for result data model?

Does `with(<related model>)` operator work as INNER JOIN?

Where to explore information about that?

Comment: Try using a good ide like PHPStorm and following the method to understand how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To know the SQL Query that Laravel execute you can use the `toSql()` function:

```php
$results = User::where(function($q) use ($request) {
    $q->orWhere('email', 'like', '%john@example.org%');
    $q->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%John%');
    $q->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%Doe%');
})->toSql();

dd($results); // output
```

Check this [article](https://laravel-news.com/quickly-dumping-laravel-queries) for more information regarding this aspect. There is also another [alternative](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging) to this approach.

Regarding your next question: **No**, Laravel doesn't do `JOIN`s. You can read a little bit about this regard in [this article](https://laravel-news.com/eloquent-eager-loading).

---

PD: If you want to know more about how Eloquent work, you can follow this good [Laracasts series](https://laracasts.com/series/advanced-eloquent).

Answer (score 1):

Since using `with()` will result in multiple SQL statements being ran, a good way to understand the underlying SQL is to use `DB::enableQueryLog()` and `DB::getQueryLog()`.

Answer (score 1):

According to SQL above you want to find Product with the name `$needle` or manufacturer name `$needle`. Guess You need `whereHas` Method.

```php
$products = Product::with("manufacturer")
                  ->whereHas('manufacturer',function($query) use ($needle){
                      $query->where("name","like","%{$needle}%");
                  })
                  ->orWhere("name","like","%{$needle}%")->get();
```

You can also prepend it to "with" method with the same query condition to obtain the relation instance it matched. In case of belongsTo you can use it without specifying condition.

Check out querying relations: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get detailed info regarding with and where condition:
- use Laravel debug bar in the development environment to see detailed info regarding queries. What's the structure, frequencies of queries etc.
- Use toSql function to dump query